# Synergy- Running dual screen on left and right with Windows and OS X in the middle

Tags: windows, macos, multiple-monitors, synergy

I have a desktop setup where i use one monitor on the left (windows) and one on the right (windows). Both are connected to the same computer. Then i got an Imac in the middle. Is there a way to get them to line up?

I found old questions about the same, but in an older version of the program. Cant see how this will line up..

My setup is like this:

(windows monitor 1) (OS X) (Windows Monitor 2)

Have sort of mounted the screens to the desk, so it will take quite som time to rearrange them..

Comment: I had a similar question involving Synergy and multiple monitors. The problem is that Synergy just doesn't have the support for multiple monitors (treats all screens on a computer as one). I think it's also not possible to have Windows separate its screens like that without some sort of virtual display or something.