# In Synergy, how to place a clinet screen in the middle of two server screens?

Tags: multiple-monitors, synergy

In synergy, how to configure a `PC server with two screens` and a `Mac client with one screen` in a way that places the Mac screen (the client) in the middle of the two PC screens (the server) ?

**P.S.:**

1. *Synergy version: 1.10.1-stable-8941241e*
2. *I'm not bothered about the mouse going around the corners as in [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1243414/in-synergy-how-can-i-configure-a-client-monitor-with-a-server-monitor-on-either). Also, I don't understand what [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1096265/synergy-running-dual-screen-on-left-and-right-with-windows-and-os-x-in-the-midd) means by "line up !"*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, with your screens being, from left to right, PC-1, Mac-1 and PC-2 (or just PC and Mac, as far as Synergy is concerned), you want a configuration that says:

- Synergy: PC is left of Mac is left of PC (and vice versa)
- Windows: PC-2 is left of PC-1

By putting the screens in the “wrong” order in Windows, you enable Synergy to intercept the mouse in the middle.

The Synergy setup would look something like this:

```
section: screens
    Mac:
        switchCorners = none
        switchCornerSize = 40
    PC:
        switchCorners = none
        switchCornerSize = 40
end
section: links
    Mac:
        left(0,100) = PC(0,100)
        right(0,100) = PC(0,100)
    PC:
        left(0,100) = Mac(0,100)
        right(0,100) = Mac(0,100)
end
section: options
    keystroke(Control+Alt+KP_Multiply) = lockCursorToScreen(toggle)
end
```

This is the solution that [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1255115/219095) refers to.

Comment: Thank you for explnantion, but where to write this configuration ?

Comment: It’s a complete `.sgc` file that you can load as a Synergy configuration. You may have to change the screen names.

Comment: I managed to change the order of the two PC screens (even though, thanks to you, it's not necessary with this .sgc file). Now I have the setup as I wanted :) Thank you